# SwiftUI: How to get scrollview to contain full list length

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a scrollview that contains a vstack that contains some text and a list. The list scrolls independently of the scrollview, leading to the effect of the text being a header for the list. I would like to have the scrollview instead have the list fully expanded so that everything scrolls together.

```
ScrollView {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(self.person.name)

                    Text(self.person.email)
                        .font(.subheadline)
                        .padding(.top)

                    Text(self.person.about)
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                        .padding()

                    List {
                        Section {
                            ForEach(self.friends, id: \.id) { friend in
                                Text(friend.name)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Spacer()
                 }
                .padding()

            }
```

This is what I get when I scroll the list:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You've effectively got two ScrollViews here.  You need to use a single `List` and place those other items as a `Section` header.  Unfortunately `List` doesn't seem to support a header for the entire view yet the way `UITableView` does.

```swift
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section(header:
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(self.person.name)

                    Text(self.person.email)
                        .font(.subheadline)
                        .padding(.top)

                    Text(self.person.about)
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                        .padding()
                }
            ) {
                ForEach(self.friends, id: \.id) { friend in
                    Text(friend.name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT: Perhaps you're not even looking for a header?  In which case, just put your desired content above the `ForEach`.

```swift
    var body: some View {
        List() {
            Section {

                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(self.person.name)

                    Text(self.person.email)
                        .font(.subheadline)
                        .padding(.top)

                    Text(self.person.about)
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                        .padding()
                }

                ForEach(self.friends, id: \.id) { friend in
                    Text(friend.name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's the result with the header and without:

[image][image]